# Call Stack not visible in IE11 debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

I am using IE11 on Windows 10 Enterprise, 64 Bit, German version.
Up to a few months ago I was able to see the call stack in the IE 11 debugger, as usual.

However, since a couple of months, I am not able to see the call stack  in the debugger anymore. This item is called in German in another way, but this is not important. My question is: How is it possible to turn on (to show) the call stack in IE 11 debugger again?

Below, please find out a screenshot of what I see in my IE11 debugger currently:

[image]

NOTE: Reading this documentation

[Debugging Script with the Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd565625(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

did not  solve my problem

Comment: I tried a lot, but I can't reproduce your problem. I think you could try to use the shortcut key `shift + alt + c` to see if you can switch to the call stack panel. If this doesn't work, I think you have to reset IE. `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `Advanced` -> `Reset Internet Explorer settings`

Comment: @XudongPeng thank you very much for your effort! Actually I found out where "the problem" is - the Call Stack section was minimized, so that only when I went over it with the mouse and tried to "drag" the most right-down scroll bar, I was able to see it again. Unfortunately, on the screenshot, it looks like the Call Stakc is missing, whereas it is actually minimized. So, thank you very much once again!

Comment: Well, it looks like your problem has been solved. You can post the plan as an answer, it can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries and errors, I found out that the Call Stack pane was actually minimized. In fact, only after I went over the most right-down scroll bar with the mouse and tried to "drag" it up , I was able to see the Call Stack again.
Unfortunately, on the screenshot I gave, it looks like the Call Stack is missing, whereas it is actually minimized.

Hope this helps other members having the same problem.